# Trying to call a navigation bar function in another class pragmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I created a navigation bar which I'm trying to call in another view controller. I set it up by calling the methods which I separated into left, center and right buttons. In my other controller I call the navbarcontroller and try and call the method for which i setup the navigation toolbar. Nothing happens, however there is no crash.

```
import UIKit

class NavBarController : UIViewController{

var screenSize: CGRect!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupNavigationBarItems()
    setupToolBarItems()

    self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
    self.view!.backgroundColor = .white

}
```

and my method for the navigation bar is this

```
func setupNavigationBarItems() {
    setupCenterNavButton()
    setupLeftNavButton()
    setupRightNavButton()
}
func showCalendarController() {
    let navController = CalendarController()
    self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
} //connect bottom bar buttons to controller
func showEventsController() {
    let navController = EventsController()
    self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
} //connect bottom bar buttons to controller

func setupNavigationBarItems() {
    setupCenterNavButton()
    setupLeftNavButton()
    setupRightNavButton()
} // top bar button setup

private func setupCenterNavButton() {
    let buttonFrame = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 165, 
height: 20))
    mainFeedButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: 80,height: 20) as 
CGRect
    mainFeedButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    peekFeedButton.frame = CGRect(x: 85,y: 0, width: 80,height: 20) as 
CGRect
    peekFeedButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    buttonFrame.addSubview(mainFeedButton)
    buttonFrame.addSubview(peekFeedButton)
    navigationItem.titleView = buttonFrame
} //center bar buttons / action setup

private func setupLeftNavButton() {
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: 
favoriteButton)
}// left bar buttons / action setup

private func setupRightNavButton() {
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: 
moreButton)
} //right bar buttons / action setup

lazy var mainFeedButton: UIButton! = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom) // button type
    button.setTitle("Main",for: .normal) //button title
    button.sizeToFit()  // size button to fit the title
    var frame = button.frame //create frame to manipulate the body
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)
    button.addTarget(self, action: 
#selector(self.showMainFeedController),
                     for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}() //mainFeed button connected to Feed Controller

lazy var peekFeedButton: UIButton! = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom) //button type
    button.setTitle("Spy",for: .normal) //button title
    button.sizeToFit()  // size button to fit the title
    var frame = button.frame //create frame to manipulate the body
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 100, height: 40)
    button.addTarget(self, action: 
#selector(self.showSpyFeedController),
                     for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()//peekFeed button frame and action setup 

lazy var favoriteButton: UIButton! = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system) //default button with blue 
text
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: 
"star").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    button.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(favoriteButton_tapped),
                     for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}() //favorites button frame and action setup

lazy var moreButton: UIButton! = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system) //default button with blue 
text
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: 
"more").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    button.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moreButton_tapped),
                     for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}() //more button frame and action setup

func showMainFeedController() {
    let navController = MainFeedController()
    self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
} //mainFeed button connected to Feed Controller
func showSpyFeedController() {
    let navController = SpyFeedController()
    self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}//peekFeed button connected to SpyFeedController
func favoriteButton_tapped(sender: UIButton) {
    print("You touched this!")
}
func moreButton_tapped(sender: UIButton) {
    print("You touched this!")
}
}
```

I then try and call the function by setupNavigationBarItems() like this

```
import UIKit

class EventsController: UIViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let navbar = NavBarController()
        navbar.setupNavigationBarItems()
        self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white

     }
}
```

I'm not sure if this a valid way. I'm still kinda new to all of this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you expect to happen, but here's what does happen:

```
    let navbar = NavBarController()
```

A completely new NavBarController object is created.

```
    navbar.setupNavigationBarItems()
```

That NavBarController object's `setupNavigationBarItems` is called.

```
    self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
```

Your code comes to an end. `navbar` was a local variable, so the NavBarController object vanishes in a puff of smoke. The end. This object was created and configured *to no purpose*.

Comment: That makes sense, so is there a way to call the     setupNavigationBarItems() method or am i stuck just creating a new one?

Comment: You haven't given enough information for me to answer that question. Obviously you _don't_ want to create a new one (as you are now doing) if you are trying to talk to one that's already on the screen. You want to _refer_ to the one that's already on the screen.

Comment: How do you refer to one? I've been trying everything short of creating a whole navigation bar with the same buttons

Comment: I said, you haven't given enough information. It depends upon the hierarchical view controller relationship between the view controller you are in and the view controller you want to talk to. However, I have answered the question you asked, i.e. why your code seems to have no effect. It's because it has no effect!

Answer (score 0):

I remember my first month in iOS way back 2015 :D, didn't have any knowledge in OOP, I didn't know too how to pass a data to another screen or class.

Anyways, you DO NOT create a new instance of your `NavBarController` class in your `EventsController`. If you want to talk to your `NavBarController` from your `EventsController`, then you will need a reference that is currently alive. You can also use `delegate` (search for that later).

So before you show or present your `EventsController` from your `NavBarController`, pass your current `NavBarController` instance to the next screen which is `EventsController`. BUT FIRST, you need to declare a variable in your `EventsController`, correct? :)

1. Declare a variable with a type of `NavBarController` inside your `EventsController` class, like so:

   ```
   var navBarController: NavBarController!
   ```
2. Then in this piece of code of yours, pass your self (the `NavBarController` instance) to the `EventsController` class before showing or presenting, take note that you mistakenly gave a wrong name to your `EventsController` new instance, so I renamed it:

   ```
   func showEventsController() {
       let eventsController = EventsController()
       eventsController.navBarController = self // THIS :)
       self.present(eventsController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
   ```
3. Lastly, instead of this:

   ```
   let navbar = NavBarController()
   navbar.setupNavigationBarItems()
   ```

Make use of your declared variable, like so:

```
self.navBarController.navbar.setupNavigationBarItems()
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: that really helps! i have a very small grasp of oop but its starting to click slowly. when i run the above code above however i get an error that says that      eventscontroller has no member 'navBarController'

Comment: Of course you need to declare the `navBarController` variable inside your `EventsController`, like this: `var navBarController: NavBarController!` .... Read again my answer :)

Comment: yea thats where im confused though because i put it inside the view did load